# Wix Boolean Property Values Don't Work

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have the following property:

```
<Property Id="UPDATEDB">1</Property>
```

A checkbox in the UI bound to that property:

```
<Control Id="updateDatabase" Type="CheckBox" CheckBoxValue="1" Height="15" Width="95" X="20" Y="74" Text="Update Database" Property="UPDATEDB" />
```

And a Custom Action which does something based on the value of this property

```
<CustomAction Id="RunDbMigration" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Return="check"
          ExeCommand='[DBMIGRATIONDIR]\DbMigration.exe' />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RunDbMigration" After="InstallFinalize">UPDATEDB=1 AND NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

If I try to pass a value of 0 for UPDATEDB from the command line:

```
msiexec /i "Setup.msi" /l* UPDATEDB=0
```

or

```
msiexec /i "Setup.msi" /l* UPDATEDB="0"
```

the value of the checkbox is checked anyway. That said, the 0 passed in seems to be respected and the RunDbMigration action is not run...

What's going on here? Why is this such rocket science?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have mentioned, Checkboxes are not boolean in a 1/0 sense, they're boolean in a null/not-null sense.

To unset from the command line - you would want to use something like

```
msiexec /i "Setup.msi" /l* UPDATEDB=""
```

Chances are that your condition is looking specifically for the value of 1 before executing your custom action, which is why your CA isn't being run.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks. Passing in UPDATEDB="" did the trick. I understood why my custom action wasn't getting run, but not why the checkbox was still checked. Now I understand that anything that's not "" means checked.

Answer (score 3):

Installer properties are either set to a value or they are not set. Internally the value is just a string, so "0", "1", "true" and "false" are the same.

A checkbox control is checked when its property is set to a value (doesn't matter what) and unchecked when its property is empty.

This command line sets the property and checks the checkbox:

```
msiexec /i "Setup.msi" /l* UPDATEDB="0"
```

This command line doesn't set the property, so the checkbox is not checked:

```
msiexec /i "Setup.msi" /l*
```

Comment: /But the default value of UPDATEDB is 1...so if I don't pass it in the command line, the checkbox is checked by default anyway.....

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the **CheckBoxValue="1"**. You find the solution for your question here: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-conditionally-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-td5539262.html